# Scanning a QR code using a raspberry pi zero or a Pi3 via a command line script

Tags: camera, display, pi-zero, bash, picamera

I need to scan a QR code via the command line when a script is run. My current setup is an epaper display with integrated 4 buttons. So far I have each button programmed to run a script to change images on the epaper. easy. But now I want to be able to attach a camera to my Pi zero and scan a QR code by using one of the buttons that activates a scanning script.

- Would a pi zero be able to do this or do I need a Pi3 instead?
- Can I scan a QR code via the command line reliably? I'm scanning blind as I have an epaper display and not an LCD. Will I have issues?
- After scanning the QR code, I need to pass this data into a nodejs script and it should output my calculated result on the epaper display. What software would be most ideal for scanning?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `zbarcam`. You can call it in a way that it terminates after successfully scanning a code, so while the user will have to aim without any visual clues, you can reliably tell them when the program has finished scanning.

`zbarcam` will output the QR code contents on the standard output, which can optionally be redirected to a file, whichever you find easier to read.